# Filter group names from one long string into two arrays depending on the characters after the group name in PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell

The Input is a String of Adgroups that looks like this:

```
group1 - add grou_2 - remove group 3 - add group_4-example - add group 5-test - remove
```

as you might notice behind every group name is an whitespace and then following an - add or an - remove.

The goal is to safe each group name that is infront of an - add into an array and every group name that is infront of an - remove into another array.
That should happen in an powerHhell script.
So that i can later on handle the group memberships with those arrays.

My problem is that the group names also can contain whitespaces or special characters like - so that i cant just match with them.

The first script i build had only - add strings as input so that i could just split it after each occurence of - add. I tried to figure out if i can also somehow work with split in this Case but i can`t come up with something that works.

When i splitt the string after - add for example my next output would look like

```
group1
grou_2 - remove group 3
group_4-example
```

and so on and i couldnt really figure out how to process that into something usefull.

My idea for regex was something simple like "(.*)- add"
But the output would just be every character before the last - add in the string.
So i somehow would need to tell him to filter that for every group occurence in the string. So either with "^" for the start of the string or behind an " - remove" or an " - add" i guess. But i really have no clue how to do that.

I might should add that the string could contain somewhat from 1 up to 20 groups.

If anyone has an Idea that doesnt involve regex or splits i would be also very grateful for that.

Comment: its " - add" will correct it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a Solution my pattern is (.*?(add|remove)) and then i pipe the different values into an array with:

`$test = $gruppen | select-string -pattern "(.*?(add|remove))" -AllMatches |  ForEach-Object {$_.Matches} |  ForEach-Object {$_.Value}`